# MODE_MULTI_PROCESS I am studying SharedPreferences, can anyone explain me what it does?

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I am studying `SharedPreference` and i didn't understand this:

`MODE_MULTI_PROCESS`

This method will check for modification of preferences even if the `sharedpreference` instance has already been loaded.

Can any one please explain this to me with an example?

Comment: Do not use `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS`. Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_MULTI_PROCESS): "MODE_MULTI_PROCESS does not work reliably in some versions of Android, and furthermore does not provide any mechanism for reconciling concurrent modifications across processes. Applications should not attempt to use it. Instead, they should use an explicit cross-process data management approach such as ContentProvider."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is sometimes desired in cases where the application has multiple processes, all writing to the same SharedPreferences file. Generally there are better forms of communication between processes, though.

`MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` is used when an application has multiple processes, all of them writing to the same SharedPref file. And an app having multiple processes is a rare thing in itself. You shouldn't anyway use `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` with sharedprefs.

Quoting the reason from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_MULTI_PROCESS),

> MODE_MULTI_PROCESS does not work reliably in some versions of Android, and furthermore does not provide any mechanism for reconciling concurrent modifications across processes. Applications should not attempt to use it. Instead, they should use an explicit cross-process data management approach such as [ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html)

Moreover, this mode is deprecated in API level 23